# FIx Issue - Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-gradle-plugin

Its not being build in my system, all the related versions - like kotlin gradle plugin version, android gradle plugin version, gradle version - all are same shared on github with the team, and its only happening in my system.

WHat could be the reason?

```
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'

    ext.gradlePluginVersion = '8.0.2'

classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradlePluginVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Gradle properties :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
```

Comment: probably lint issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185418482

Answer (score 0):

This is because your kotlin version is

```
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
```

But the module want a 1.7.1 version

You have two options, you can downgrade to 1.7.1 or try to update the module version, maybe he handle 1.8.21

But if you use compose look to : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin?hl=fr

You see

```
compose 1.4.3   kotlin 1.8.10
```

You can't use a kotlin version higher than 1.8.10 if you would like to use compose.

You certainly have the same problem with your module.